# Refactor C# OR statement using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How can I write this OR statement better, allowing for growth in number of values?

```
var isNewFile = (progressID == 10 || progressID == 20 || progressID == 21);
```

I was thinking of this:

```
var isNewFile = progressID.Contains (10,20,21)
```

OR using Linq:

`.Select` or `.Contains`

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's wrong with that? Do you need a dynamic list of possible IDs?

Comment: No, just wanted to keep it cleaner (looking) ..

Comment: To make it cleaner, I would use an enum or constants instead of the "magic numbers" .. and likely leave the `||`s alone for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For something this simple, I think using the `||` is fine, however, if you need to use the list of acceptable integers more generally or avoid hard-coding the set in a single expression<sup>1</sup>, you can use something like this:

```
var newFileProgressIds = new[] { 10, 20, 21 };

var isNewFile = newFileProgressIds.Contains(progressID);
```

Or possibly use a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var newFileProgressIds = new HashSet<int> { 10, 20, 21 };

var isNewFile = newFileProgressIds.Contains(progressID);
```

<sup>1: Of course, in these examples, the values are still hard coded in one place, but precisely how you generate the list is unimportant.</sup>